# Multiples compilaciones al presionar F5 en el navegador

Tags: javascript, laravel, aplicación-web, vite

me ha estado pasando un problema bastante extraño, cada vez que presiono F5 en el navegador me aparece en la terminal "build started...", esto es lo que hice:

- Hago mi script de vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

Y en mi package.json tengo definidos mis scripts:

```
"dev": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"watch": "vite build --watch"
```

Ahora bien, cuando ejecuto "npm run watch" al inicio todo parece normal pero en cuanto hago una modificación se empiezan a ejecutar muchos "build started...", no sólo eso, también me sale en el navegador un:

- "Vite manifest not found at: /var/www/html/projectname/public/build/manifest.json"

Y si sigo presionando F5 a veces sale en la consola del navegador un:

- "404 not found http://localhost/build/assets/app-fc1fe159.css"

Además que con cada nuevo F5 la terminal donde ejecuto el "npm run watch" se llena de nuevos mensajes de "build started..." (Aclaro que no está en bucle ya que sólo aparecen esos mensajes si recargo la página desde el navegador sin modificar directamente ningún archivo).

Y en cuanto paro el comando del watch recargo la página y ya puedo ver el contenido con todo y sus estilos.

No sé si se pueda hacer algo al respecto, por ahora cada que quiero compilar un nuevo cambio sólo ejecuto "npm run build" pero es muy tedioso hacer eso todo el tiempo para ver mis cambios.

¿A alguien más le ha pasado? :'(

Comment: Consulta: Por que usas `npm run watch` en lugar de `npm run dev` como se recomienda en la [documentación de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#running-vite)? Agregaste [`@viteReactRefresh`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#react) en la plantilla blade que carga los assets?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ usé npm run watch por costumbre, y además de que instalé el proyecto y los paquetes que necesito en una maquina virtual con ubuntu server (para asegurarme que desarrolle en algo lo más parecido a prod) donde no funcionó lo del npm run dev, pero si lo que hago es una mala práctica pues no sería nada complicado acostumbrarme a "npm run dev" y me olvido de este problema de una vez jajaja